# "Static member function overrides a virtual function in a base class" caught by gcc and clang but not VC++

Tags: c++, gcc, visual-c++, clang, virtual-functions

Most likely one does not want this sample to compile:

```
#include <iostream>

class C {
public:
    virtual void Foo() {
        std::cout << "From C\n";
    }
};

class D : public C {
public:
    static void Foo() {
        std::cout << "From D\n";
    }
};

int main() {
    D d;
    d.Foo();
    return 0;
}
```

It does not compile indeed in gcc and clang (Error "Static member function overrides a virtual function in a base class"). It does, however, compile in Visual C++, uttering **From D** to console on run. Even with the latest VC++ RC 2017 compiler (v141) with options *ISO C++ Latest Draft Standard (/std:c++latest)* and */permissive-* ([link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2016/11/16/permissive-switch/)) turned on.

Which compiler is right? Is this error by the Standard? If so, does it mean that VC++ does not follow the Standard in this case?

Comment: I'm fairly sure that's illegal. Most likely a MSVC bug. Also, the compiler version generally is MSVC14.1 or more specifically 19.10.24930 on my installation.

Answer (score 3):

It's definitely a MSVC bug. ISO C++ doesn't permit that.

[class.static.mfct/2](http://www.eel.is/c++draft/class.mem#class.static.mfct-2) (emphasis mine):

> *[ Note:* A static member function does not have a this pointer.  *— end note ]* A static member function shall not be virtual. **There
>   shall not be a static and a non-static member function with the same
>   name and the same parameter types ([over.load])**...

Comment: "Ill-formed" does not mean "should not compile". The language definition requires that the compiler issue a diagnostic. I haven't seen any mention here of whether that's what happens with this code.

Comment: @PeteBecker, Noted; and Corrected. Thanks. :-).  I am still learning to be pedantic with these standard terms.

Comment: Your emphasis concerns overloading, but `C::Foo` does not participate in overloading, being in separate scope, unless introduced with `using C::Foo;` in `D`. If `C::Foo` was not virtual, `static D::Foo` would simply hide it.

Comment: @PeteBecker VC++ does not emit warning even with "All Warnings" mode.

Answer (score 1):

**10.3:2** states that `D::Foo` must be virtual (even if not declared so).

> If a virtual member function vf is declared in a class Base and in a
>   class Derived, derived directly or indirectly from Base, a member
>   function vf with the same name, parameter-type-list (8.3.5),
>   cv-qualification, and ref-qualifier (or absence of same) as Base::vf
>   is declared, then Derived::vf is also virtual (whether or not it is so
>   declared) and it overrides 111 Base::vf...

And **9.4.1:2** states that it can not be virtual

> [Note: A static member function does not have a this pointer (9.3.2).
>   —end note ] A static member function shall not be virtual. There shall
>   not be a static and a non-static member function with the same name
>   and the same parameter types (13.1). A static member function shall
>   not be declared const, volatile, or const volatile.